# Nifi ListenHTTP/HandleHttpRequest External Access

Tags: docker, callback, apache-nifi, httpserver

I would like to use the NiFi to have an HTTP listener that I would be using it as a callback url for and external API.

So, I got to know about `ListenHTTP` and `HandleHttpRequest` which acts as a HTTP server that keeps listening on a defined path. The NiFi server is running on Docker and setup is secured(`HTTPS`) and the UI is accessible via `https://nifidev.xyz.com/nifi/`

Now I setup the `HandleHttpRequest` to port `443` and base path to `/callback`

[image: HandleHttpRequest Properties]

When I try to do some `POST` commands using `cURL` from the docker container, a flowfile is generated with the details that is passed

```
curl --location 'http://nifidev:443/callback' --header 'Content-Type: text/plain' --data 'foo=bar
userid=12345
startdate=1530576000
enddate=1530698753'
```

> Note: `nifidev` is the container name that is used in the cURL command

Now, when I try to do the same via postman the `POST` call fails

POST Request : https://nifidev.xyz.com:443/callback

```html
<h1>System Error</h1>
<h2>The request contained an invalid host header [<code>nifidev.xyz.com:443</code>] in the request
    [<code>/callback</code>]. Check for request manipulation or third-party intercept.</h2>
<h3>Valid host headers are [<code>empty</code>] or: <br/><code>
<ul><li>127.0.0.1</li>
<li>127.0.0.1:8443</li>
<li>localhost</li>
<li>localhost:8443</li>
<li>[::1]</li>
<li>[::1]:8443</li>
<li>nifidev</li>
<li>nifidev:8443</li>
<li>10.0.4.11</li>
<li>10.0.4.11:8443</li>
<li>nifidev.xyz.com</li>
</ul>

</code></h3>
```

I have also tried to make the call `POST /callback HTTP/1.1 Host: nifidev.xyz.com`
Response -> `You may have mistyped... but we'll try to redirect you in 5 seconds.`

Would the HTTP server be accessible from the internet, do I need to add any additional configurations to make it accessible. The whole setup is on Docker so is it something to do with the container to be made publically accessible.

##### Setup Details

- Docker NiFi
- Web Proxy Traefik
- NiFi Secured HTTPS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As all the setup is on Docker and we have a Webproxy (Traefik), I was able to route the requests `POST` by adding a rule in the Traefik labels.

```yaml
# HTTP Listener
- traefik.http.routers.Nifi-listener.service=Nifi-listener
- traefik.http.routers.Nifi-listener.entrypoints=websecure
- traefik.http.routers.Nifi-listener.tls=true
- traefik.http.routers.Nifi-listener.rule=(Host(`hostname`) && Path(`/path`))
- traefik.http.services.Nifi-listener.loadbalancer.server.port=<port>
- traefik.http.services.Nifi-listener.loadbalancer.server.scheme=https
```

With this labels added into the NiFi Docker compose file, the requests redirection was taken care by Traefik.